# Interpolation Search

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

How can I implement a Genric Interpolation Search in Delphi? I've tried porting it from 
[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_search). However it returns the wrong result.

```
function Search(var A: TArray<Integer>; const Index, Count, Item: Integer): Integer;
var
  L, H, M: Integer;
begin
  L := Index;
  H := Count;
  Result := -1;
  while (A[L] <= Item) and (A[H] >= Item)  do
  begin
    M := L + ((Item - A[L]) * (H - L)) div (A[H] - A[L]);
    if A[M] < Item then
      L := M + 1
    else if A[M] > Item then
      H := M - 1
    else
      Exit(M);

    if A[L] = Item then
      Exit(L)
    else
      Exit(-1);
  end;
end;

var
  A: TArray<Integer>;
  I: Integer;
begin
  A := TArray<Integer>.Create(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7);
  I := Search(A, 0, High(A), 5); // Returns -1;
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Comment: Well, so what is wrong with that code ?

Comment: I don't know anything about generics in Delphi, but the best way is likely to include a generic function parameter - assuming Delphi allows it - that accepts the `Item`, the array and two indices, and returns the interpolated index.  This will replace the computation of `M`.  If you can't do it with a generic parameter, they you'll have to do with a function pointer.

Comment: @Gene The function is not generic. It operates on arrays of integers

Comment: @user3764855 What do the `Index` and `Count` parameters mean? They appear to be needless.

Comment: Use low(A) and high(A) no?

Comment: You asked how to make a generic function. I'm telling you to make it generic by including a generic function parameter that does the interpolation.  Some languages (for example Ada) will let you do this just fine. I don't know if Delphi will.

Comment: @Gene I get you. My [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24577093/how-to-remove-empty-nil-elements-from-array) at one of the asker's recent question showw how to do this in a generic way. Perhaps the asker just needs to read that answer again.

Comment: Anyway, it's difficult to make it generic. The algo doesn't make much sense away from the real line.

Comment: Algorithm is fine for values on real line

Comment: It's really not hard to write this stuff. It won't be that much faster than bisection though.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I've figured it out. A beautiful solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full working solution. Can probably optimized further. It works even if there are duplicates, it will just output the first index aswell it will work with strings if you use something like `LevenshteinDistance`.

```
type
    TCompare<T> = reference to function(const L, R: T): Integer;
    TArrayManager<T> = record
        class function InterpolationSearch(var A: TArray<T>; const Index, Count: Integer; const Item: T; const Distance, Compare: TCompare<T>): Integer; static;
    end;

class function TArrayManager<T>.InterpolationSearch(var A: TArray<T>; const Index, Count: Integer; const Item: T; const Distance, Compare: TCompare<T>): Integer;
var
  L, H, M, C: integer;
begin
  L := Index;
  H := Count;
  Result := -1;
  while L <= H do
  begin
    if L = H then
      M := L
    else
    begin
      M := L + (Distance(Item, A[L]) * (H - L)) div Distance(A[H], A[L]);
      if M < L then
        M := L
      else if M > H then
        M := H;
    end;
    C := Compare(A[M], Item);
    if C < 0 then
      L := M + 1
    else
    begin
      H := M - 1;
      if C = 0 then
      Result := M;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 4):

This code piece:

```
  if A[L] = Item then
      Exit(L)
    else
      Exit(-1);
```

should be **outside** the body of while cycle

Comment: It seems that algorithm returns first one if there are no duplicates and last one if there are duplicates.

Comment: Algorithm doesn't take duplicates into account - just returns the first matching value - first, second, last, any duplicate.